# After upgrading/reinstalling some app using Homebrew, how to automatically set its notification settings?

Tags: macos, homebrew, permission, notifications, settings

I found each time after I upgrade or reinstall Evernote, macOS prompts me for setting its notification permission settings. Could I make it sticky so I don't have to reset it each time? Or, could I set it with some command so I can run it together with the homebrew command to upgrade/reinstall?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just install the non-homebrew distribution of Evernote or, at least, don't use brew to update it. The latter isn't even supposed to happen, which is why you are un/re-installing it to update. The cask system in brew isn't really that useful and it is not intended to be used for updates.

See [Why aren’t some apps included during brew upgrade?](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-arent-some-apps-included-during-brew-upgrade) in the brew manual.

Comment: The reason I use Homebrew is to automatically update as many as possible softwares using cron jobs on multiple computers.